# What does the URI's name mean in Android XML namespace?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've read [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) and a bunch of related SO questions but I still have a few.

```
<layout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:whatever="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
```

As far as I know, prefix `android` refers to *Android default* attributes; prefix `whatever` - to *application*'s attributes and included libs as well (e.g. *Support Library*); prefix `tools` - to *Android default* attributes but they are set only in *edit mode*.

But I couldn't find much about the Namespace URI. So my questions are:

1. The URI purpose is to distinguish namespaces. But what does the URI **name** mean?
2. Why the hell is it named `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` or `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` and not something else?
3. In theory, can I create my own URI name and parse XML with that on my own (e.g. to create a `View`)?

P.S. Where can I read more about the way Android creates a `View` class from XML?

Comment: that is the prefix for you to use it after words. You will use `android` as `android:layout_width`, `android:background`, etc. Same way for `whatever`, `tools`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace for a starter. The prefix such as `android` can be anything, it is processed by the XML parser before being fed to android-specific tools. It's just a convention that it is called `android`.

Comment: You guys are talking about the `prefix`. My question is about the `Namespace URI`
@laalto in your link above there's an answer on my 1st question. But it didn't clear up things much